# Send object from android with ksoap2 to c# webservice

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, ksoap

I m trying to send a complex object to me web service and return a string value but my logcat from android returns Null Refference

the full code ksoap2 send the object

```
    Questionnairekeyval qk = new Questionnairekeyval(5, 8, "Questionnaire1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");


    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Questionnairekeyval");
    pi.setValue(qk);
    pi.setType(qk.getClass());
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    // 2. Set the request parameters
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.addMapping(WS_NAMESPACE, "Questionnairekeyval",
            new Questionnairekeyval().getClass());

    // 3. Create a HTTP Transport object to send the web service request
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);
    // httpTransport.debug = true; // allows capture of raw request/respose
    // in
    // Logcat

    // 4. Make the web service invocation
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    String result;

    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) { // SoapFault =
                                                // FAILURE
        SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
        throw new Exception(soapFault.getMessage());
    } else {
        // SoapObject = SUCCESS
        SoapPrimitive soapObject = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        result = (soapObject).toString();

        Log.wtf("result SOAPObject", result + " " + soapObject);

    }
```

C# get the object and return a string

```
     [WebMethod]
    public String putAnswers(Questionnairekeyval reponse)
    {

        int a = reponse.idClient;
             return Convert.ToString(a);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the name of the proprety in the java request it was Questionnairekeyval but in the webservice was reponse so its basicly that the problem why it returns null